# A method is protected, but I got the modifier of the method by reflection, the modifier is public. IDE is Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, reflection

A class like this:

```
public class MethodSubject {

    public String getString(String str) {
        return "hello";
    }

    protected void setStr(String str) {

    }

    int getID(int t) {
        return 100;
    }

    private void setID(int id) {

    }
}
```

Then, I use reflection to get the method

```
Class<MethodSubject> clz=MethodSubject.class;
Method[] methods=clz.getDeclaredMethods();
for(Method method:methods){
   int modifier=method.getModifiers();
   if ((modifier& Modifier.PUBLIC)==1){
      Log.e("target,",method.toString());
   }
}
```

then, the log is:

```
public int ...MethodSubject.getID(int)
public String ...MethodSubject.getString(java.lang.String)
public void ...MethodSubject.setStr(java.lang.String)
```

why the modifier is changed?

Comment: Are you sure you are looking for correct logs? because I have just tested your scenario amd its not printing method name with protected modifier

Comment: same by me, is wonrking pretty good

Comment: I'm pretty sure what i say. I test these code in Eclipse, it's work fine. But, if It's work in AndroidStuio, the log is what I write there.

Answer (score 0):

I think something in your setup is wrong. I just ran this simple test here:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class Test {

 void foo() { };
 public void bar() {};
 protected void foobar() {};

 public static void main(String[] args) {
   Class<Test> clz = Test.class;
   Method[] methods=clz.getDeclaredMethods();
  for(Method method:methods){
  int modifier=method.getModifiers();
    if ((modifier& Modifier.PUBLIC)==1){
      System.out.println("target: " + method.toString());
    }
  }
 }
}
```

and as expected, that prints:

```
target: public void Test.bar()
target: public static void Test.main(java.lang.String[])
```

Conclusion: java behaves as expected; something in your setup is wrong.

Comment: I test in eclipse, it's work fine. But, I test in AndroidStuio, the log is incorrect.